# fwrite not working in included file

Tags: php, include, fopen, fwrite

I have one php file "test.php" which have below code

```
$file = fopen("../testwrite.php","w");
echo fwrite($file,"<h1>this is for testing</h1>");
fclose($file);
```

now I have one more php file named original.php in which I have included test.php. 
But when I run original.php then fwrite function have no affect. "testwrite.php" is not writing.

but if I direct run test.php then it is working and testwrite.php will write but content.

content of original.php is below,

```
<?php include_once 'test.php'; 

// other process ?>
```

So what is issue here?

Comment: Can you add the content of original.php ?

Comment: Are those files in the same folder, or in different locations?

Comment: content of original.php is below,
`<?php
include_once 'test.php';

// other process
?>`

Comment: files are in different folder